# How do I create a =CountDistinct in SSRS based on a query

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I need help creating an expression in SSRS based on this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT person_id) FROM person_table
WHERE (employed = 'Y' or title = 1) 
or    (start_date = '' or start_date = '00000000'
or     start_date > CONVERT    (VARCHAR,GETDATE(),112))
```

All that I have so far is this

```
=CountDistinct(IIf(Fields!no_unresolved_allergies_ind.Value = "Y",Fields!MRN.Value,Nothing))
```

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Answer (score 0):

With limited information, i will try along these lines

```
=CountDistinct(
IIF(
((Fields!employee.Value = "Y" OR Fields!title.value = 1) OR 
(Fileds!start_date.value = " " OR Fileds!start_date.value = "00000000") OR
(Fields!start_date.Value > FORMAT(NOW(),"yyyyMMdd")),Fields!MRN.Value,Nothing
        )
```